# I am trying to calculate side C of a triangle using pythagoras, using a class.. C#

Tags: c#, class

This is the last assignment of my C# course.. In this assignment i program using a class.
I can make this all work without use of a class,  but can not (thusfar) with.

here is the code:

```
public class Pyt
{
    private double _Rh1;
    private double _Rh2;

    public Pyt (double rh1, double rh2)
    {
      _Rh1 = rh1;
      _Rh2 = rh2;
     }

    public double _Som()
    {
      return _Rh1 * _Rh1 + _Rh2 * _Rh2;
    }

    public double _Som2()
    {
      return Math.Sqrt(_Som);///here is where the problems arise.. at the last
     }
       /// calculation.. it gives error, can not convert from 
       ///method group to double.
 }
```

as you might have read, it gives error can not convert from method group to double.

I have thus far tried several things, my method seems ok (using 2 sum variables)

Can anybody help?

greetings,

Stefan

Comment: `_Som` just refers to the method - it doesn't *call* the method. I suspect you want `Math.Sqrt(_Som())` instead. (I'd also strongly advise you to remove those underscores and use more meaningful names. Choosing good, readable and conventional names is a core part of programming.)

Comment: I also recommend reading Microsofts [C# Coding Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) as parts of your code do not follow the conventions.  It's not an error, but many people might find in unprofessional.

Comment: The are some ways to [Format your code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022#:~:text=Edit.ExpandSelectiontoContainingBlock-,Format%20document,-Ctrl%2BK%2C%20Ctrl), and/or to [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML on Stackoverflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

`_Som` is just the function. You want to caculate the square root on the **result** of the function. To do that you need to invoke the function using the parenthesis.

```cs
public double _Som2()
{
    return Math.Sqrt(_Som());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `_Som` is a function for calculating the sum of squares of the two sides. You can't take the square root of a function.

You have to use the function by calling it, and take the square root of the result that the function returns.